# Path dependcy and delta epsilon proofs

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I have this major confusion with multi-variable delta epsilon proofs.

Basically, I have this example:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^4 - 4y^2}{x^2 + 2y^2}$$

Now by path dependency, we have the limit doesn't exist:

Suppose $y = mx$.

Then: $$ \frac{x^4 - 4y^2}{x^2 + 2y^2} = \frac{x^4 - 4m^2x^2}{x^2 + 2m^2x^2} = \frac{x^2 - 4m^2}{1 + 2m^2}$$

Thus as $x \rightarrow 0$, the limit is path reliant and doesn't exist.

However if I try to do a delta epsilon proof:

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and suppose **x** $= (x, y)$.

Suppose $0 < ||$**x**$|| < \delta$.

Note $\frac{x^4 - 4y^2}{x^2 + 2y^2} 
\leq \frac{||\textbf{x}||^4 - 4||\textbf{x}||^2}{||\textbf{x}||^2 + 2||\textbf{x}||^2}
\leq \frac{||\textbf{x}||^2 - 4}{1 + 2}
< \frac{||\textbf{x}||^2}{3}
< \frac{\delta^2}{3}$

Let $\delta = 3\sqrt\epsilon$.

What's wrong with the above? Doesn't that imply the limit equals 0?

Comment: Your fourth line from below, is incorrect. and even, Why not $\delta^2$?

Comment: You incorrectly used your triangle inequality : $||x^4-4y^2||\le ||x^4||\mathbf{+}4||y^2||$.

Comment: $|x|\ne |y|$ in general.   And you've misapplied the triangle inequality.